# MySQL from JAVA: LOAD DATA INFILE skips rows from input file

Tags: java, mysql, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

I am trying to input a 10 million line text file into a MySQL table using Java. The file has two columns separated by a white space character and I am using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to input the data to a table with two columns. The first column contains an integer and the second a varchar. However, the data passed in the database are not 10 million but 9981770. The structure of the table is:

```
st.execute("create table if not exists test 
    (id bigint NOT NULL, word varchar(80)) 
    ENGINE=MYISAM PARTITION BY KEY(word) PARTITIONS 40;");
```

I am partitioning the table to speed up the insertion and also because I want to add an index later on the word column since I want to retrieve the ids of specific words. I don't think that this causes the problem however. The `LOAD DATA INFILE` command is:

```
st.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+PATH+
    "' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';");
```

I would be grateful for any advice as how to go about solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have two recommendations for you:

1. you should checkout the error log for errors.
2. log the output into a file and and grep it for the 'err' chars.

   cat load.log | grep -i err

I bet you'll find an error that explains why some rows were not inserted.

Comment: hello Adi, thank you for your answer. I have never used the error log of mysql. Although I don't get any errors when I execute the LOAD DATA INFILE command. I have also tried running it from the MySQL console and again no errors reported. Also I forgot to mention I am running all these on Windows 7. Is it possible to explain to me how to log the output?

Comment: log in to your mysql server and run the following: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_error'; It will show you the log file location...

Comment: yeap I already checked that... It was the only file that seemed like an error log. It doesn't have any errors logged...

Answer (score 0):

I think these might be the causes:

- Some lines on your text file is not separated by white space
- Could be that that text on some of the lines are too long
- Could be that some of the first column isnt really an integer

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I am constructing this file manually and I am sure that the format is correct. Two columns separated by white space. The first column is the counter and the second is the word. I didn't put the ID column as auto increment because I want to be able to partition on the second column of the table.

Comment: It seems that your code is correct. I also experienced it in the past. And to what I know, it will ignore the insert if something is wrong in the format of your text file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but in my case I wrote the CSV file in Java before calling LOAD DATA.  However, I forgot to close the CSV file, so it had not been completely written to disk before the LOAD DATA started.